# Preparing excel workbook for importing into SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, excel

I am trying to import some data into sql using the import and export data wizard. In excel i have a column with 8 numbers. However when i get these in the import wizard said column is displayed as being double. and when i import it i get overflow errors. I then go back to excel, select the cell, format them as being a number with no decimal places. Then i go to the "edit mappings" in the import wizard and change the destination to numeric(8,0).  I get those overflow errors as well.

Would like if i could get a way to better format the data in excels to import better

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import your table into a temp or staging table with a larger data type; validate and clean your imported data; then load it into your real table.  If you can't always enforce the data type in your Excel doc, then make it easier on the server side to import your data, then manipulate it there.

Comment: yea i figured id write script to manipulate it.
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

I had a project that ran into this problem last year.

What I ended up doing is I imported the data from Excel to Access.  Then import from Access to SQL.  I don't remember the specifics, but it solved most of my issues.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the format of the column in Excel makes a difference to the import process (although I could be wrong about that.)

My guess would be that either one of your numbers is 9 or more digits, or one of them has a very small fractional component that's small enough not to appear in Excel but which the wizard detects.

You're certain that this column is the one with the overflow errors, by the way?  Does it tell you what row has the problem?

Comment: Im searching high and low for the issue. for example i have a cell with 31110244 (ALONE). I set the format the cell to be a number with no deci. places. I open the wizard and i see in "edit mapping" that the datasource is nvarchar(250) so i say w/e. then i import it into SQL(works perfectly). Then when i try to copy it into my table where 31110244 is stored as numeric i get the error Arithmetic overflow error for type varchar, value = 31110244.000000.